# Using RxJS event streams for simple sequence management

Tags: javascript, rxjs, event-stream

I'm trying to learn how to think in event streams, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it by testing it out on some contrived scenarios. The following scenario I'm stuck on:

Let's say I have two buttons, we'll call them `A` and `B`. `A` can be clicked at any point. `B` can also be clicked, but only if `A` was clicked immediately before. In other words, the `B` can never be clicked twice in a row. Here is the corresponding marbles diagram (where x means the event is ignored):

```
clickA$ --------o--------o-------->
                |        |
clickB$ --o--o--|--o--o--|--o--o-->
          x  x  |  |  x  |  |  x
logA$   --------o--|-----o--|----->
                   |        |       
logB$   -----------o--------o----->
```

The standard approach would be to store state in flags and make decisions using if/else control blocks, as shown below:

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var flag = false;

a.attachEventListener('click', function(e){
  flag = true;
  console.log("A");
});
b.attachEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    console.log("B");
  }
});
```

I feel like there should be a clean, concise way to do this without flags or some super messy event stream merging but it's escaping me. Is there a `someMethod()` in RxJS such that we can do the following to have the desired effect?

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var a$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(a, "click").map(e => "A")
var b$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(b, "click").map(e => "B")
           .someMethod(a$)
a$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
b$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption that `logB$` is a hot source, just like `clickA$`.

Looks like `logA$` = `clickA$`.

For `logB$` :

```
logB$ = clickA$.flatMapLatest(function (clickA){
          return clickB$.take(1);
        });
```

`flatMapLatest` allows you to take a value from `clickA$`, and associate it to a stream, here `clickB$.take(1)`. `flatMapLatest` will hence emit the values from that stream till it completes, which it will after emitting the first emitted value from `clickB$` (because of the `take(1)`). When a new value from `clickA$` arrives, the previous observable derived from the previous value is unsubscribed to, and the observable derived from the new value is subscribed to. That gives you your expected behaviour.

Documentation links :

- [flatMapLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md)
- [flatMap operators in RxJS](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

Comment: Thanks @user3743222. I see what you're trying to do, however it's not working for me. Take a look: http://jsbin.com/watepijuzi/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Oh, I think what we needed was b$.take(1) rather than logB$.take(1). Brilliant. Thank you!!

Comment: I guess my take away is to get familiar with flatMap... what we could perhaps call... "higher-order streams"?

If you can update the answer and let me know I'll make sure you get a lovely answer badge and upvote!

Comment: yeah sorry, I wrote that a bit quick. Corrected now.

Comment: higher-order streams... yes, that's that. If you know about monads, `flatMap` is like the `join` operation. It flattens a sreams of streams to a stream. But `flatMapLatest` is more like a switch. It replaces a stream with another one, based on values from a source stream.